# Using generate to create module ports in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, rtl

I am trying to do something like this:

```
    `define PORTS 4
    module mulitplexer
    (
      input logic clock,
      
    generate
     for(genvar  n = 0; n < `PORTS; n++) begin 
        output  a_t       multiplx_a_[n],
        input   a_fc_t    a_multiplx_[n],
        input   b_t       multiplx_b_[n],
        input   logic     ready_[n],
     end
   endgenerate

    input logic reset
    );
```

But, I get a warning about missing a port in the ANSI port list. I have not been able to find any answer to what I am doing wrong.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can use for/generate in module definitions. Instead you should use an array and a parameter that defines the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that cannot be done in SystemVerilog; actually several things.

You can't use a generate construct in the middle of a another construct, in your case, a module header declaring a port list. And even if you could, you cannot use generate to build an identifiers like `logic ready_0, ready_1`, etc. Nor could you use it to declare individual elements of an array, like `logic ready_[0], ready_[1]`.

You have several alternatives, the easiest is declaring these ports as arrays.

```
`define PORTS 4
module mulitplexer
(
  input logic clock,
    output  a_t       multiplx_a_[`PORTS],
    input   a_fc_t    a_multiplx_[`PORTS],
    input   b_t       multiplx_b_[`PORTS],
    input   logic     ready_[`PORTS],
input logic reset
);
```

You can also create struct with these as fields, but you would need to separate the inputs form the outputs. 
Finally, you could find a macro pre-processor that allows you to write a `for loop as a macro. SystemVerilog does not have that built in.

Comment: @dave_59, Hi, what if I want to do `port mapping` using generate? Can we do port mapping (not port declaration) using just array index? I remember using verilog preprocessor years ago (which expands loops).

Comment: @ChanKim Not sure what you mean. Please ask a separate question

Comment: @dave_59, I later realized I can just do normal `.port(sig)` when port and sig is array. (I was thinking of for loop to connect each port/signal array elements).

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of chipverify.com:

> A generate block cannot contain port, parameter, specparam declarations or specify blocks. However, other module items and other generate blocks are allowed. All generate instantiations are coded within a module and between the keywords generate and endgenerate.
> -- https://www.chipverify.com/verilog/verilog-generate-block

I need that for myself for instantiating 4 identical modules except direction of one port.
I am getting back to you if I figure out how to do.